# Show the function is a open map

Tags: continuity, open-map

I was searching for a function which is open but not continuous and I got the following function:

$f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$
\begin{equation}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
2x& \text{$if\ 0\leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$}\\
x& \text{$if\ \frac{1}{2}< x \leq 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now I want to know how can we prove the function is open? I tried as:

Suppose $A$ is open in $[0.1]$

$\implies A=[0,1]\cap O $,for open set $O$ in $\mathbb{R}$
Now I want to show $f(A)=f([0,1]\cap O)$ is open in $[0,1]$.
How should i proceed  to show $f$ is a open map??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $a,b\in(0,1)$ with $a<b$. Then$$f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)=\begin{cases}(2a,2b)&\text{ if }b\leqslant\frac12\\(2a,1]\cup\left(\frac12,b\right)&\text{ if }a\leqslant\frac12\text{ and }b\geqslant\frac12\\(a,b)&\text{ if }a>\frac12.\end{cases}$$So, $f\bigl((a,b)\bigr)$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$. Nw, do the same thing for $f\bigl([0,1)\bigr)$ and for $f\bigl((a,1]\bigr)$. Since every open subset of $[0,1]$ is an union of these three types of sets, you're done.

Comment: Isn't it $(2a,1]\cup (\frac{1}{2},b) $?

Comment: @mathstudent Right. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: But how to show $(2a, 1]\cup (\frac{1}{2},b) $ is open in [0,1].I know $(\frac{1}{2},b) $ is open but show to show $(2a, 1]$ is open on [0,1]?

Comment: The set $(2a,1]$ is an open subset of $[0,1]$, since$(2a,1]=[0,1]\cap(2a,\infty)$ and $(2a,\infty)$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$.